# How can I make python detect missing packages or apps

Tags: linux, python

I'm making a script for *Ethical Hacking* purposes and I want to have a first function that detects and shows the user what packages they need to install before they can continue. For example, I would like it to detect if the user has `nmap` or `aircrack-ng` in their Linux systems!

Comment: @JeffSchaller Iḿ using linux mint!

Comment: If I `import foo` and module `foo` is not found by python, I get ab exception that says: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'` - is that not enough? If not, what more do you want?

Comment: `pip list` or `pip freeze` will show installed Python modules. It should be enough to just compare the output what modules the user needs to run the script. As previously mentioned, if the module isn't there then they will see the error that it's not found.

Comment: @NickD I want it detect packeges like aircrack-ng that arent python related !

Answer (score 2):

For Python modules I use code like this:

```
# Make sure we have all our necessary modules
allOK=True
for m in ['requests','json','yaml','argparse','re','traceback']:
    try:
        globals()[m]=importlib.import_module(m)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Python module "%s" is required, please use "yum install python-%s" to install it.' % (m,m)
        allOK=False

if not allOK:
    print 'One or more modules missing, exiting.'
    exit(1)
```

Comment: Might be better to just catch `ImportError` instead of all exceptions

Answer (score 0):

For packages, just trying to install them is the easiest, but something like parsing the output of `rpm -qa` (or equivalent for other packaging schemes) would work.  If it's a Python module, you could have a `try`-`except` statement where the `except` clause can install the package containing the module and try the import again.

Was that the question, or are we all confused?

Comment: That's ok but I steal need something that detects packages not related to python like aicrack-ng!

Comment: Right, so only the first half of my answer is relevant. Parse the output of your package manager.